# Python Pandas not creating multiple tabs in excel file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a python script that pulls from a 3 rd party API. The script runs for 3 different cities in loop and creates a data frame for each city. Then I transfer the data frame to an excel sheet as a tab. Below is the code.

```
    sublocation_ids = [
                {
                  "id": 163,
                  "name": "Atlanta, GA"
                },
                {
                  "id": 140,
                  "name": "Austin, TX"
                },
                {
                  "id": 164,
                  "name": "Baltimore, MD"
                } 
             ]
filter_text = "(headline:coronavirus OR summary:coronavirus OR headline:covid-19 OR summary:covid-19) AND categories:{}"

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(excel_path)
    for sub in sublocation_ids:
        city_num_int = sub['id']
        city_num_str = str(city_num_int)
        city_name = sub['name']
        filter_text_new = filter_text.format(city_num_str)
        data = json.dumps({"filters": [filter_text_new], "sort_by":"created_at", "size":2})
        r = requests.post(url = api_endpoint, data = data).json()
        articles_list = r["articles"] 
        articles_list_normalized = json_normalize(articles_list)
        df = articles_list_normalized
        df['publication_timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['publication_timestamp'])
        df['publication_timestamp'] = df['publication_timestamp'].apply(lambda x: x.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = city_name)
        writer.save()
```

The current issue I am facing is only one tab is getting created in the excel sheet for the first city "Atlanta,GA" I pull the data for from the API. How to create the tab for each and every city in the directory or does my code has any issue?

Comment: i see two possible errors, first where is writer initalised? outside of loop? two your calling `writer.save()` with every loop thus overwriting the sheet each time. call it at the end of your loop

Comment: @Datanovice Check above is how the code is currently set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't speak for your code as I can't run it 'filter_text' seems to be a function you've written but not included.

essentially you have one of two errors I can see,

first it's not clear where you are initialising the `writer` object.

2nd you're overwriting the sheet with each loop - move it outside of the loop.

`pd.ExcelFile` can be used as a context manager - so you need to close/save it.

```
def close(self):
    """synonym for save, to make it more file-like"""
    return self.save()
```

---

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('file.xlsx')

for sub in sublocation_ids:
    city_num_int = sub['id']
    city_num_str = str(city_num_int)
    city_name = sub['name']
    filter_text_new = filter_text.format(city_num_str)
    data = json.dumps({"filters": [filter_text_new], "sort_by":"created_at", "size":2})
    r = requests.post(url = api_endpoint, data = data).json()
    articles_list = r["articles"] 
    articles_list_normalized = json_normalize(articles_list)
    df = articles_list_normalized
    df['publication_timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['publication_timestamp'])
    df['publication_timestamp'] = df['publication_timestamp'].apply(lambda x: x.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = city_name)

writer.save() # move this after you've finished writing to your writer object.
```

## Sheets as dictionaries

if you're curious of the innards of the class, use `.__dict__.` on the object so you can see the metadata.

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('file.xlsx')

df.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='Sheet1')
df.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='Sheet2')
print(writer.__dict__)

{'path': 'file.xlsx',
 'sheets': {'Sheet1': <xlsxwriter.worksheet.Worksheet at 0x11a05a79a88>,
  'Sheet2': <xlsxwriter.worksheet.Worksheet at 0x11a065218c8>},
 'cur_sheet': None,
 'date_format': 'YYYY-MM-DD',
 'datetime_format': 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS',
 'mode': 'w',
 'book': <xlsxwriter.workbook.Workbook at 0x11a064ff1c8>}
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to include I have already defined the object check above edited code.

Comment: the solution is clear, @error2007s just move the save outside of the loop.

Comment: Nope still the same issue only one tab is getting created

Comment: Also if this was a loop issue the Tab that the Excel file should have must be Baltimore MD right. But the current Excel file has tab of Atlanta GA @Datanovice

Comment: Ok yours is a the correct answer writer.save() needs to be outside loop. I was adding it at other place. It is working perfectly now

Answer (score 2):

See this bit from the `df.to_excel()` [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html):

> If you wish to write to more than one sheet in the workbook, it is necessary to specify an ExcelWriter object:

```py
df2 = df1.copy()
with pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx') as writer:  
    df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet_name_1')
    df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet_name_2')
```

So you may need to pull `writer.save()` outside of the loop.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to include I have already defined the object check above edited code.